# How to make a PHP Class Property only changeable by a class Method

Tags: php, class, properties

```
class Item {
     public $itemname;

     somekeyword $error; //The correct keyword I want to find

     public function insertData() {
          $query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('".$this->itemname."')";

          try {

                  //HERE THERE IS A NICE CODE TO EXECUTE THE QUERY AND SO...
                  return true; //Returns true on success
          } catch(PDOExecption e) {
                 $this->error = $PDOObject->errorInfo();
                 return false; //Returns false on FAIL but the Object has a property with the error information
          }

     }

}
```

How can I make the Property error only changeable for this class methods? I don't want it to be changeable outside by another class or file.

Does the keyword "protected" works to make it Readable outside but not changeable?

Thank you!

Comment: Off-topic but your code is potentially susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, yes, I just coded it like that for the example, but in the actual code I have Prepared statements and security validations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protected` makes it unaccessible from outside, there is no read-only keyword for properties in PHP, to get its value you have to define getter function:

```
class Item {
     protected $error; 
     public function getError(){
         return $this->error;
     }
}
```

or use some 'magic':

```
class Item {
     protected $error; 
     public function __get($name){
         return $this->$name;
     }
}
```

The later one allows you to access this property just by `$object->error;` but is less readable and slightly slower then predefined function call.

Answer (score 0):

You either want private or protected. If you want it to be accessible by classes which extend your class, protected, otherwise, private.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php